# Warning in system.log related to failed to open stream in Magento 1.9.4

Tags: system.log, magento-1.9.4.0

Recently I have started seeing issues in Magento logs. I have not been able to debug why this started happening. Please help !

Following are the logs:

> Warning: include(Crypt/Hash.php): failed to open stream: No such file
>   or directory  in /lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94 Warning:
>   include(): Failed opening 'Crypt/Hash.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='/app/code/local:/app/code/community:/app/code/core:/lib:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php:/mob/lib/phpseclibgoogleshopping')
>   in /lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

Comment: What version of php are you running?

Comment: check \lib\phpseclib\ directory Hash.php is there or not?